# undo a git merge on a local branch which is never pushed up

Tags: git, git-merge

I am new to git, and have created a local branch by following `git checkout -b child` syntax, then I went on and merged someone else's branch using `git merge origin/parent`.
**Note**: I did not push my local branch i.e. `child` up yet.

1. `git status` shown `nothing to commit, working tree clean` - which is confusing, my limited knowledge may be the cause **Update** -  I learned that git merge commits the code too, I should have probably used `git merge --no-commit`
2. I want to undo my merge to start afresh - How do I do it?

**Disclaimer** There are tons of git related questions out there, which maybe tangentially related to the above questions, but please realize that for a new guy it is quite overwhelming, internet is boon and bane.

**EDIT - 1** I am also reading whether I should have performed `git merge` first place, or should have used something like `git fetch`

**EDIT - 2** `git reset HEAD~x` is NOT what I am looking for, I just want to un-do the whole git merge

Comment: My favourite resource for fixing git issues: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? (Note that a merge is just a commit, as you'll see if you run `git log`) [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: thank you @DaveyDaveDave how do I undo a whole merge, `git reset HEAD~` only took me one commit back

Comment: `git reset --hard` doesn't work either @DaveyDaveDave

Comment: you can use `git reset HEAD~x` where `x` is the number of commits before the last you had. Ex. `git reset HEAD~3` in case your merge is counting and you had 2 commits in this new branch

Comment: @ignacio my point is I just merged somebody else's branch to my local, do I need to really learn what they have committed, I just want to undo git merge, and start with a clean slate.

Comment: I am also reading whether I should have performed git merge first place, or should have used something like `git fetch`

Comment: `git reset` almost certainly *is* what you are looking for here. What to reset *to* depends on whether `git pull` actually did a real merge, or whether it did a fast-forward instead of a merge.

Comment: `git reset --hard` will throw away uncommited changes, but `git merge origin/<somebody_else_branch>` commits the code too. Is there another variant of `git reset` which I should look for, @torek?

Comment: If the merge that `git pull` ran was a true merge, you got a new merge commit, and you would want to reset to `HEAD~1`. If the merge that `git pull` ran was a fast-forward, you'd want to reset to the commit that was in place before the fast-forward operation (which is almost, but not quite, a simple checkout). If you had work that you had not committed, a true merge would not be possible in general and at least some if not all fast-forward cases would be rejected so there wouldn't be anything to do. Are you sure you had uncommitted work?

Comment: Note that you can do a soft or mixed reset: typically to get back to the old commit, you'd do a hard reset, but if you had uncommitted work, you would probably want soft or mixed instead. If you got a fast-forward that preserved uncommitted work, you'll want one of those followed by individual checkout operations, which is messy and painful and not something I like to do, which is why I'm careful not to use `git pull` at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo merge action, you can follow this :

1. `git reflog`, this will show you every event you have done in git
2. copy `<hash-id>` commit action bellow your merge action in there
3. paste that `<hash-id>` into this command `git reset --hard <hash-id>`, this will reset git HEAD.